# show html and php code inside javascript after detection width of window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want some this type of coding for my user where if width is less than 1000 than I will show mobile design otherwise shows desktop design but cannot run HTML and PHP inside a Javascript if else loop

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($(window).width() > 1000) { 
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <?php echo $a ;  ?>
            </body>
        </html>
    } else {
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <?php echo $b ;  ?>
            </body>
        </html>
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have no idea what your question is trying to say, but it sounds like you should be using CSS media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: i m saying if window width is less than 1000 px then shows different design and php value and if window width more than 1000px then shows different html design and php value .But my html tag and php is not working in javascript if else loop

Comment: You should definitely be using CSS media queries for that then - it's what they were designed to do. Your current pattern cannot possibly work.

Comment: i m using bootstrap but if else loop cannot work for me

Comment: It won't work because you mix server and client side code. Use media queries if you use boostrap then make boostrap tutorial about RWD

Comment: If you're using bootstrap it has a responsive system built in. Look at the grid system they offer.

Comment: You're better off using media queries in the CSS as @RoryMcCrossan explained, but if you HAVE to do it this way - check for the window width and load a PHP page that creates a session variable stating to use the mobile version - then from that use PHP conditions of what you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use media queries if you want to apply some css that depends on browser size.

Your script won't work because you mix client and server side code if you still want to use javascript then check code below

```
if (window.innerWidth > 500) {
   alert('above 500');   
} else {
   alert('below or equal to 500');   
}
```

Some links you may want to read:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries
- http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html

Notice: if you want execute PHP code that depends on browser width you need to do AJAX call.

Comment: yup this alert is working but i want to show html and php coding how can i do ?

Comment: You need to do AJAX call. It depends on logic, if you have same data but you need change layout then it's better to use media queries and RWD, if you need different data then make AJAX call

Comment: is there any other way to do window width in php function its easy to do for me if php can

Comment: PHP can't detect browser width because it is server side. You can pass browser width via AJAX to PHP or via form. There's no other way to do it.

Comment: can you tell me how to do with ajax and php